# Combining results when using switchMap and forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an http service which returns an object array, and by using this results am calling another service as given in the example. Now how can I combine the intermediate and final results at the end. For eg: result1Data[0] + result2Data[0] etc..

```
var result1= this.service1.getData();

result1.pipe(
  switchMap(data => {
    let result2 = data.map(result1Data => {
      return this.service2.getData(result1Data);
    });
    return forkJoin(...result2);
  })
).subscribe(result2Data => {
   
 //combine result1Data and result2Data
 
})
```

Comment: `result2` is merely an array of observables which would later be resolved to `result3`, did you mean `result1`?

Comment: You are right, I have edited the question.  I need to combine the intermediate result1Data and the result of the corresponding service call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it could be implemented:

```js
var result1 = this.service1.getData();

result1.pipe(
  switchMap(result1Data => {
    return forkJoin(result1Data.map(this.service2.getData))
      .pipe(
        map(result2Data => {
          //combine result1Data and result2Data ()
        })
      )
    )
  })
).subscribe(result3 => {

  // allready combined

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a combination of `switchMap` and `map` from `rxjs/operators` and `combineLatest` from `rxjs`

```js
const result1$ = this.service1.getData();

const result2$ = result1$.pipe(
  switchMap(result1Data => this.service2.getData(result1Data))
)

const combinedResult$ = combineLatest([result1$, result2$]).pipe(
  map(([result1Data, result2Data]) => { 

    // combine result1Data and result2Data here

    return combinedResult
  })
 )

combinedResult$.subscribe(result3 => {

  // already combined

})
```

Comment: result1Data is an array, so need forkJoin there.